# Selenium WebDriver WebTable getData: How to get a value of "td" if it is depends on another "td"

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am facing one issue where the value of a one particular cell(td) in a webtable depends on another cell (td)..

Example:

1. Use http://www.espncricinfo.com/new-zealand-v-australia-2015-16/engine/match/914239.html and click on Full score...
2. Now I want to get a batsmen name who is unbeaten (Need "Not out" batsman from New Zealand 1st Innings. In this case "TA Boult")
3. But "TA Boult" and "Not out" are 2 different td's of a same "tr".

Can someone please guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: Provide code you try so far and errors you faced. Do not ask for a complete solution!

Comment: I was unable to copy/paste my code, so unable to add the code what I wrote..

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath would solve this issue for you:

```
//table[contains(@class,"batting-table")][1]//td/a[.="TA Boult"]/../../td[@class="dismissal-info" and contains(text(), "not out")]
```

You may want to make the selector for the top table a bit more specific, but essentially this XPath is doing the following:

1. Find the first table that contains the classname "batting-table"
2. Get all the `td` elements within this table
3. Get all the `a` elements within the `td` elements
4. Specify that the `a` element's text must be the player you are searching form, in this case, TA Boult.
5. Use `/../..` to select the parent of the parent of the `a` element that has the text "TA Boult". So if the parent of the `a` tag is `td`, the parent of the `td` tag is `tr`.
6. Now that we are in the row containing any matching `a` tags, we can search within this row for the `td` tag with the "dismissal-info" class that contains the text "not out".

From there you could then use `/../..` again to return the entire row as the result of the XPath.

So essentially, you are searching for a row, then searching for a child, then searching for a parent, then searching for a different child and then returning a correct row.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so...

```
//all tr elements.

IList<IWebElement> tableTRCollection = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//table[@class='batting-table innings']")).FindElements(By.TagName("tr"))

//in every tr all td elements will be:

IList<IWebElement> tableTDCollection;

foreach(IWebElement tr in tableTRCollection )
{
tableTDCollection = tr.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
}

//in td collection take all td

foreach(IWebElement td in tableTDCollection )
{
string tdText = td.Text;
}
```

and so on...

after you get all the collections you can get everything.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answers.. I was able to find an answer after a lot of struggle, but  found solution is almost same that Ben has suggested.

I did not try another suggested solution though..

Below is the code...

```
WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='full-scorecard']/div[2]/div/table[1]//td[@class='dismissal-info'][contains(text(),'not out')]/ancestor::tr/td[@class='batsman-name']"));
```